# How to access configuration in a Lagom service at startup?

Tags: java, lagom

I am migrating my current app in Spring/J2EE to Lagom. I am working in Java. I need to read variables from the configuration (application.conf in resources folder). In the implementation module, I try to inject configuration as a class variable like this

@Inject
private Configuration config

but when I access this config object in the constructor, it gives null pointer exception.

The whole code is like this

```
import play.Configuration;

public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Inject
    private Configuration config;

    public SomeServiceImpl() {
         //getting configuration from application.conf
         // gives exception as config is null.
        String key = config.getString(“key”);
    }

    @Override
    public ServiceCall<Request, Response> send() {
         //works here, does not give exception
         String key = config.getString(“key”);
    }
 }
```

Sorry, I should have been clear from the beginning. I have edited the original question. I get null pointer exception when I try to read from configuration object in constructor but I am able to use it in service call implementation. I want some way in which I can access the configuration in application.conf at startup and possibly store in some config class which can be accessed anywhere later.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything yourself? if so, please share your code

Comment: I did search the api and docs but could not find a way to do it. The service api - https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/api/index.html does not have any method which lets you run code after the service has been created.

Comment: Do you mean `service` has been created as (object has been constructed?)

Comment: Have you tried running your code in the service constructor itself?

Comment: Yeah, I tried in constructor of the service but it does not work as the code I want to execute has to be run after the service has been created. I could not find anything related to this in docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "after service has been created"? Do you mean "after the service starts listening on an http port", or "after the service has connected to the database", or what? What is your actual precondition to running your code, what are you trying to achieve?

The equivalent to @PostConstruct is to put it the code in the constructor, what can't you do in a constructor that you can do in @PostConstruct?

Comment: I have edited the original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, when an object is instantiated, the first thing that happens (before anything else can possibly happen) is the constructor is invoked. After that, frameworks like Guice (which Lagom uses) are free to inject things, but they can't do it until the constructor has been invoked. So, all your `@Inject` annotated fields will be null when the constructor is invoked, there is nothing you can do to work around that.

So, don't use field injection, use constructor injection, eg:

```
import play.Configuration;

public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

  private final Configuration config;

  @Inject
  public SomeServiceImpl(Configuration config) {
     this.config = config;
     String key = config.getString("key");
  }

  @Override
  public ServiceCall<Request, Response> send() {
    String key = config.getString("key");
  }
}
```

Constructor injection is not just recommended for this use case, you should be using it everywhere, it avoids all these potential issues.